# how to assign value to textbox usingJavascript/ jquery when texbox is not having id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is sample HTML code

```
<input name="DPAAP" type="hidden" value="Estambul Turquía - Todos los aeropuertos (IST)">
<input type="hidden" name="acArrValues" value="IST|Todos los aeropuertos|Estambul||Turquía|TR|110TR-010041.0138428.94966">
```

I can not change HTML code . How shall I assign another value to above textbox using Javascript/jquery

Comment: Not a `textbox`but no biggy.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$('input[name="DPAAP"]').val('whatyouwant');
```

or if you want the second change try this:

```
$('input[name="acArrValues"]').val('whatyouwant');
```

Obviously you on't have multiple input with that name and if you have to change it when the page is loaded and not when for example click on a buottn you need to include the code inside `$(document).ready()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="DPAAP"]').val('whatyouwant');
    $('input[name="acArrValues"]').val('whatyouwant');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select it by the name:

```
$('input[name="DPAAP"]').val('Your value');
```

But you have to make sure there are not inputs with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByName("DPAAP")[0].value = "your value";
```

With jQuery:

```
 $('input[name="DPAAP"]').val('your value');
```